# Why does my PHP while loop stop after a certain point?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

When I run the script, the output stops on line 397 i.e. the output looks like "397. 0e4001". [Link to the script results](http://173.254.28.121/~iskusno1/hash/). Why does the script stop? It should continue until it meets the criterium.

```
<?php

$key = "iwrupvqb";
$num = 0;
$str = "";

while ($str != "000000") {
    $hash = md5($key . $num);
    $str = substr($hash, 0, 6);
    echo $num . ". " . $str . "</br>";
    $num++;
}

?>
```

Comment: It's a type juggling issue. change != to !==

Comment: `Why does the script stop` It meets criterium and stops?

Comment: @JohnConde I tested your suggestion, and I get 200k+ items in the loop with no signs of stopping..I think the script is flawed

Comment: It will take a while for PHP to loop through 200,000 items.

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks, that fixed the issue. Now if I could just stop the browser form crashing. :)

Answer (score 0):

As John Conde pointed out, the issue was in the comparison operator i.e. it needed to be changed from != to !== .